# Performance of selector

Tags: jquery, performance

I've done [a test](http://jsperf.com/jquery-with-vs-without-context-selector) with performance of a jQuery selector.

The two selectors I have tested:

```
selection_width = total_width - ($('#commands .minimap').outerWidth() + $('#commands .actions').outerWidth());
```

And:

```
var commands = $('#commands');
selection_width = total_width - ($('.minimap', commands).outerWidth() + $('.actions', commands).outerWidth());
```

The second one is way faster than the first one. Is this correct or did I screw up the test somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first test, jQuery uses `document.querySelectorAll()` (relatively fast) twice. In the second case, jQuery uses `document.getElementById()` (very fast) once and `document.getElementsByClassName()` (fast since you declared a context) twice.

Answer (score 1):

In the second one you store the commands element so it's not searched again. Thus you get better performance.

Comment: But it still has to search the `minimap` and `actions` elements right? What make the second one faster than? I don't get it :P

Comment: @PeeHaa, Sure, How will Jquery find it?

Comment: @PeeHaa, The command element isn't re-searched again + 'actions'+ 'minimap'. only the 'actions' and 'minimap'.

Answer (score 1):

The first statement has to analyze the complete DOM tree and look for the element `#commands` twice, whereas the second one only needs one check over the whole DOM tree. The search for the elements `.minimap` and `.actions` is faster because for that, jQuery only has to iterate the children of `#commands`, and not the whole document.